# In Ruby, is there a way to find the class that responds to a method call?

Tags: ruby, introspection

So, in Ruby, if I have a class hierarchy that looks something like (very symbolically)

`A` < `B` < `C` < `Object`

and have a method `"foo"` defined in class `C`, is there some bit of *introspection* that allows me to determine that `C` is the class defining the method that responds to `A.new.foo`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes... do `A.new.method(:foo).owner`. It will give you class `C`. Read [`#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-owner).

Answer (score 1):

[Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-owner) is purpose-built for this, but this could also be used:

```
A.ancestors.find { |c| c.instance_methods(false).include? :foo }
```